# sine function in python gets wrong value

Tags: python

```
def sin_x(b):
    a = b
    if a=="pi" or a=="π":
       return 0
    else:
        x=float(a)
        return sin_function(x)
def factorial(b):
    if b==0:
        out=1
    else:
        out=1
        for i in range(1,b+1):
            out*=(i)
            i+=1
    return out
def sin_function(X):
    k=0
    sin=0
    last_term=(((-1)**k)*(X**(2*k+1)))/factorial(2*k+1)
    while abs(last_term)>1*10**(-8):
        sin+=last_term
        k+=1
        last_term=(((-1)**k)*(X**(2*k+1)))/factorial(2*k+1)
    return sin
print (sin_x(50))
```

hello, I'm trying to build a sine function that gives exactly the same value as a calculator without implementing the math function. The main issue I have right now is that whenever the input is bigger than 35, the function starts to give the false value, and several exceptions if I keep increasing the input value. Can someone modify it to make it works exactly as a calculator? (it takes radians as input)

Comment: Floating point numbers don't give you the precision that you would need to evaluate Taylor polynomials of sufficiently high degree that far from the origin. Use elementary trig identities. All trig evaluations can be reduced to evaluations in the range `[0,pi/4]` Even then, it wouldn't be exactly like a calculator, since Taylor series are not often the best choice for numerical approximations.

Comment: ok, how am I suppose to write this out in code?

Comment: First understand the math (e.g. coangle identities) and then implement the math in code. You could be somewhat lazy and use high enough degree so that you get good convergence on `[0,2*pi]` and then use the fact that e.g. `sin(x % (2*pi))` by periodicity.

Comment: lol, I'm really a noob, can you give details by modifying my code? then I see it more clearly.

Comment: A minimal fix is to put `x = x % (2*math.pi)` at the start of your function. Use `3.1415926536` instead of `math.pi` if you want to do it with no imports. It would be better to delve into the trig a bit more to get is down to `[0,pi/4]` rather than `[0,2*pi]` but if you don't care about saving cpu cycles, this should work.

Comment: you mean to put x = x % (2*pi) under the "else" part? Oh I think you want me to put under the sin_function part

Comment: oh my god, it works, thank you!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several possible reasons, the first of which is that the commonly known Taylor expansion for sin(x) is only valid around the origin, more specifically the range [-pi, +pi]. This figure explains why:

[image]

Of course, you could shift the Taylor expansion to be based around any point, but it's probably more intuitive to just map the input radians into a value that falls within the above range, e.g. 5*pi/2 should map to pi/2. The following Python code does this:

```
PI = 3.141592653589793  
x = 5*PI/2  
pi_factor = int(x / PI)  
adj = pi_factors if pi_factor%2 == 0 else pi_factor + 1  
rad = x - PI*adj  

print(rad)  
1.5707963267948966
```

Next up, your factorial function returns an int, which can lead to unexpected behavior when dividing. To be safe, make it return a float:

```
return out*1.0
```

Lastly, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the Taylor expansion is simple. [Take a look at the expansion for sine on the first page of this tutorial](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-5-exploring-the-infinite/part-b-taylor-series/session-99-taylors-series-continued/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses99c.pdf). I've implemented my own version below, which uses your factorial function:

```
def sin_function(x):

    # Doing this instead of math.abs
    sym_fact = -1 if x < 0 else 1
    y = -x if x < 0 else x

    # convert input radians to [-PI, +PI]
    PI = 3.141592653589793
    pi_factor = int(y / PI)
    adj = pi_factor if pi_factor%2 == 0 else pi_factor + 1
    rad = y - PI*adj

    # Taylor expand, increase num_terms for more precision
    total = 0
    num_terms = 7
    f_sign = 1
    for i in range(1,2*num_terms+1,2):
        total += f_sign * pow(rad, i)/factorial(i)
        f_sign *= -1

    return total*sym_fact
```

The first two lines are exploiting the fact that sin(-x) = -sin(x). I avoided using math.abs() to keep it "pure" Python. If that's not a restriction for you, then the code can be simplified a little with math.abs() and math.pi. Also, you can increase the precision by increasing the number of terms used in the Taylor expansion (currently set to 7). Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) but your first sentence is misleading at best. The Taylor series for `sin(x)` is *valid* for all real numbers since it has an infinite radius of convergence, though it is only *practical* near the origin. The problem with using it for things like `x = 35` is simply the practical problem of 64-bit floats not being able to handle the large powers and factorials in the higher degree terms that would be required for the target accuracy. Not a good use of CPU cycles, but `x = 35` can be easily handled by switching to the `decimal` module.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are correct, obviously the Taylor expansion can be based around any point, not just the origin. I've edited my post to clarify.

Comment: The Taylor series *at the origin* has an infinite radius of convergence. There is no need to shift to get convergence for all real numbers. It is true, though, that any specific Taylor polynomial (which is a finite approximation of the full series) will only give good approximations on a finite interval.